# Get substring from path

Tags: bash

I have path and want to retrieve one folder name in between path . 
How can we achieve that.

```
/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy/abc/pqr
```

so from above path I want string "EXT001-STA2020"

this is the only variable value in the string

rest string will always be the same.

sed or grep

anything will work for me ..

any help is appreciated.

Comment: on SO we encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so kindly do add the same and let us know then.

Comment: @Ashu007 : What is the general rule to identify, which part of the path you want to have? Is it always the 3rd component? Will it also be always an absolute path or can it also be a relative path?

Comment: word between  "RelWork/"   and   "/StandDeploy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cut`:

```
echo "/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy/abc/pqr" | cut -d '/' -f4
```

Store output in a variable:

```
$ part="$(echo "/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy/abc/pqr" | cut -d '/' -f4)"
$ echo $part
EXT001-STA2020
```

Using `grep` + `sed`:

```
$ echo "/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy/abc/pqr" | grep -o 'RelWork.*/StandDeploy' | sed 's,^RelWork/,,' | sed 's,/StandDeploy$,,'
EXT001-STA2020
```

Comment: can we assign output of this command to any variable  .. store output to variable

Comment: @Ashu007: see updated answer. Notice that `$` is a prompt, it's not a part of the command.

Comment: can we use grep or sed anyway to achieve this?

Comment: @Ashu007 see updated answer

Comment: Thank You very very Much Arkadiusz Drabczyk

Answer (score 1):

Using parameter substitution:

```
var='/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy/abc/pqr'
var=${var%/StandDeploy*} # remove suffix `/StandDeploy*`
echo "${var##*/}"        # remove longest prefix `*/`
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
basename $(dirname "$yourPathVariable")
```

Comment: It will work for "/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy"                  but my scenario is "/tmp/RelWork/EXT001-STA2020/StandDeploy/abc/pqr"             sorry  but I have modified it now

Comment: length of the path can be anything